# How to retry a request until i get a valid dynamically generated value in response using karate dsl

Tags: dsl, karate

I am sending a request to fetch the API ID from backend but because my backend is slow it doesn't give back the ID in one go and that's making my test case fail in the first try. Though it passes if I try again, but that's not ideally it should work. I tried putting a sleep, but that doesn't look promising either.

My test case is :

Given URL storeURL

And param query =

When method get

Then status 200

- call read('Sleep.feature')
- def APIIDStr = response.list[0].id
- print 'APIID from Store is: ', APIIDStr

Can i do something here so that if APIIDStr is empty in the first go , it tries to fetch again until it gets a valid value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Please refer to the documentation on how to implement polling using JavaScript: https://github.com/intuit/karate#polling

```
function(x) {
  while (true) {
    var result = karate.call('get.feature');
    var greeting = result.response;
    karate.log('poll response', greeting);
    if (greeting.id == x) {
      karate.log('condition satisfied, exiting');
      return;
    }
    karate.log('sleeping');
    // uncomment / modify the sleep time as per your wish
    // java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

EDIT - also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

Comment: can add retry on framework? because if return 5xx that user want to retry some times, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The follow code can correctly run now:

```
Feature:
  Background:
  * url 'url'

  Scenario:
  * def input =
  """
  {
    'form': {},
    'query': {},
  }
  """
  * path '/rest/n/test'
  * params input.query
  * form fields input.form
  * method post
  * status 200
  * math response contains { result: 1 }
  * eval if (response.result != 1) karate.call('delete-user.feature'))
```

So, I hope hope `retryPost` method which can retry-post the scenario (it can auto check status).

or:

```
...
* eval if (responseStatus == 5xx) retryPost/retryGet/retryPut
* eval if (response.result != 1) retryPost/retryGet/retryPut
```

Here `retryPost/retryGet/retryPut` only re-run the section code.

for example:

```
Feature:
  Background:
  * url 'url'

  Scenario:
  # section 1
  ...
  * method post
  * eval if () retryPost # only re-run section 1

  # section 2
  ...
  * method post
  *eval if () retryPost # only re-run section 2
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: interesting, can you open a new feature request - I think the idea to specify 2 things a) boolean / predicate expression and b) polling interval - it seems to make sense

Comment: one more thing - there is a `karate.match()` JS call possible in Karate - I normally don't encourage it - but maybe it fits for this requirement

Comment: @PeterThomas ok, I'm willing.