# How to pass the background response value of the to another feature json in function value using Karate

Tags: karate

I have got the response in the background to one of the request and passing to the function for polling purpose and need to run until specific condition met. In that function, I need to pass the values to the calling feature JSON file

```
  while (true) {
  var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature') packageid; -- package id
```

is response of another request

I followed the similar way as mentioned but in that not passing any parameter. 
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/933d3803987a736cc1a38893e7039c4b5e5132fc/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature

But i am getting the below error

> feature(com.intuit.karate.testng.KarateTestngTest):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: packageid,
>   ReferenceError: "packageid" is not defined in  at line number 1

Comment: @Peter Thomas I don't whether this request will come under your bucket or not.So adding you here

Comment: @PeterThomas done.I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: are you trying to pass the varaible packageid as an input to your feature file ? @user:1980552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input for call inside js should be given as

```
karate.call("<featureFile>",yourInputVaraible);
```

refer this on doc
https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object

Comment: its correct way of passing arguments?    var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature','#(packageid)'); I tried with '<packageid>' still i get the same error

Comment: var packageId = {"packageid":packageid}; var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature',packageId );

Comment: '#(packageId)' this way of assigning json values from variables only works on  feature file.

Comment: @ here I followed the similar logic as mentioned in below url but the loop is never ending once the condition has met it should stop but again its calling the same scenario again. Any idea on that? https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/933d3803987a736cc1a38893e7039c4b5e5132fc/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature

Comment: your above code says its while(true), this would always be an infinite loop unless until you have a valid break/ return condition inside your loop, the code also has an if-condition for breaking the while loop (if (greeting.id == x). make sure you have a valid condition (please refer Answer 2 in this : 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596736/how-to-add-conditional-wait-for-a-response-in-karate')

Comment: got it, let me try it out.Thank You again

Comment: I followed the same as you mentioned still its looping even after 1st time is completed   function(status) {
   var actualstatus = null
    while (actualstatus != 'Complete') {
      var packageId = {"packageid": packageid}; 
      var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature',packageId); 
      var greeting = result.response;
    
      if(greeting.payload.progressStatus == status) 
      { actualstatus = greeting.payload.progressStatus
       return;} 
      actualstatus = greeting.payload.progressStatus
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); 
      }
     }
  """

Comment: this is the scenario: after that function:    * def packageId = packageid
   * def result = call read('Progress.feature') {packageid: '#(packageId)'}
   * def current = result.response
   * def status = 'Complete'
   * call waitUntil status

Comment: This look like a javascript related question. Can you please create a question under javascript and karate tags

Comment: ok sure. Thank You but i see the tags are separated. It doesn't have javascript and karate

Comment: posted it by adding both tags,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds wrong to me, maybe you have a typo.

Also please read the docs carefully. Only JSON is supported as a `call` argument.

The best way for you to get support is to follow this process, else no one can help you with the limited info you seem to be providing in your questions.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sure. I tried to add sample code but it throwing error so that is the reason i questioned in a wage

Comment: Given url 'url1'
  And  request someJson
  When method POST
  Then status 200 
  And  def packageid = response.payload.packageID
 * def waitUntil = 
  """
   function(status) {
    while (true) {
      var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature') {packageid: '#(packageid)' };
      var greeting = result.response;
      if(greeting.payload.progressStatus == status) 
      { return;} 
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); 
      }
     }
  """  As mentioned above the passing of variable to the function is correct?

Comment: are you trying to pass the varaible packageid as an input to your feature file ?

Comment: Answered :@user1980552

Comment: Any idea how to use it?

Comment: refer my answer below or [karate Doc](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object)