# Karate framework retry until not working as expected

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate framework with JUnit.

Using this feature:

```
Given path 'save_token'
And request
"""
{
  "token": "test_token"
}
"""
And retry until response.tokens ==
"""
[
    "test_token"
]
"""
When method POST
```

I'm having this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.intuit.karate.core.MethodMatch.convertArgs(MethodMatch.java:60)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.Engine.executeStep(Engine.java:141)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioExecutionUnit.execute(ScenarioExecutionUnit.java:171)
```

When response.tokens list is empty:

```
{
    "tokens": []
}
```

I don't understand why == does not work in this case (it should return false, and keep retrying).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`retry until`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#retry-until) expression has to be pure JavaScript and the special Karate match keywords such as `contains` are not supported, and you can't do a "deep equals" like how you are trying, as that also is not possible in JS.

EDIT: in 0.9.6. onwards you can do a complex `match` in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Also note that JsonPath is *not* supported, which means `*` or `..` cannot appear in the expression.

So if your response is `{ "tokens": [ "value1" ] }`, you can do this:

```
And retry until response.tokens.includes('value1')
```

Or:

```
And retry until response.tokens[0] == 'value1'
```

To experiment, you can try expressions like this:

```
* def response = { "tokens": [ "value1" ] }
* assert response.tokens.includes('value1')
```

At run time, you can use JS to take care of conditions when the response is not yet ready while polling:

```
And retry until response.tokens && response.tokens.length
```

EDIT: actually a more elegant way to do the above is shown below, because `karate.get()` gracefully handles a JS or JsonPath evaluation failure and returns `null`:

```
And retry until karate.get('response.tokens.length')
```

Or if you are dealing with XML, you can use the `karate.xmlPath()` API:

```
And retry until karate.xmlPath(response, '//result') == 5
```

And if you really want to use the power of Karate's `match` syntax, you can use the [JS API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-match):

```
And retry until karate.match(response, { tokens: '##[_ > 0]' }).pass
```

Note that if you have more complex logic, you can always wrap it into a re-usable function:

```
* def isValid = function(x){ return karate.match(x, { tokens: '##[_ > 0]' }).pass }
# ...
And retry until isValid(response)
```

Finally if none of the above works, you can always switch to a custom polling routine: [`polling.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature)

EDIT: also see this answer for an example of how to use `karate.filter()` instead of JsonPath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60537602/143475

Don't forget that you can set timeouts in Karate for servers that take time to connect / respond: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398877/143475

Comment: What kind of object is response.tokens that you can apply contains() method? I was looking for javascript arrays docs and they use includes(). I'm looking for something like containsAll().

Comment: it is actually a java `List`. maybe you just need to do this `And retry until karate.match(response, { tokens: '#(^^expected)' }).pass` - refer to "contains short-cuts" in the docs

Comment: Great. Last question, how can you break retry until expressions? Line was too long and enter does not work.

Comment: I know that I can write a separated function, but I want to put it there in an expression of several lines.

Comment: @italktothewind you can't. but remember, "open source" ;P

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that as of 0.9.6, if the response is itself a JSON array, `retry until response.contains(expected)` would not work (it did up to 0.9.5), and should be replaced with `retry until response.includes(expected)`.

Comment: @TzachZohar not sure about that. maybe yes if it is a primitive (e.g. string) or an array of primitives