# Using Retry until and with JSON Path Evaluation

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to build a polling feature using retry until syntax. My test is using retry in two scenarios.

First one works fine and but the second retry scenario is always failing. with msg `too many retry attempts: 2`

Here is how my feature looks like

```
Given path brokerResult.activationPlan
    And header Authorization = oauthToken
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And retry until response.blocks == '#[13]' && karate.jsonPath(response, "$.blocks[?(@.block_status=='ACTIVE')]")== '#[3]'
```

Execute some more scenario to change the state.

```
 Given path brokerResult.activationPlan
    And header Authorization = oauthToken
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And retry until karate.jsonPath(response, "$.blocks[?(@.block_status=='FINISHED')]") == '#[3]'
```

Here this scenario always fails.

I am on Karate version: 0.9.2

My question is does JSON path evaluation works with retry until which I am assuming yes as my first scenario works. what is that I am missing to make the second scenario work.

Comment: i am not sure if we can use `marker` for ***non-match*** js evaluation. but i am surprised to see it worked for the first scenario, can you try using karate.match(karate.jsonPath(response, "$.blocks[?(@.block_status=='FINISHED')]"), '#[3]')

Comment: by `marker` i meant `'#[3]'` and please try this instead `karate.match(karate.jsonPath(response, "$.blocks[?(@.block_status=='FINISHED')]"), '#[3]').pass`

Answer (score 1):

No, JSON-path or "fuzzy match" markers do NOT work for `retry until`.

Please read this answer for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

This should give you a hint to solve your case:

```
* def isActive = function(x){ var temp = karate.jsonPath(x, "$.blocks[?(@.block_status=='ACTIVE')]"); return temp.length == 3 }
* def response = { blocks: [{ block_status: 'ACTIVE' }, { block_status: 'ACTIVE' }, { block_status: 'ACTIVE' }] }
* def result = isActive(response)
* match result == true
```