# Retry Untill is not working for xpath conditions in karate framework

Tags: karate

I am using karate framework for my api testing. It seems the retry logic not working as expected for xpath conditions. I want to retry the same request until some response value to met expected value. Find the sample and error  below

code
[image: Code]

And the error is

retry condition evaluation failed: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location path was expected, but the following token was encountered:  =

Comment: next time please don't paste screenshots, use code so people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes XPath is not supported, you need to come up with a JS expression to do your logic. Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

Hint - you can do XPath operations in JS like this:

```
* def response = <root><result>5</result></root>
* def fun = function(r){ return karate.xmlPath(r, '//result') == 5 }
* fun(response)
```