# Reuse of feature files with retry until

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

Having some stunning success with Karate. Working on end-to-end tests that use 'retry until' timeout on a GETs in order to wait for a specific parameter value within the response body. The parameter is expected to change state from A to B as data processing completes in the system under test. Interested to learn about patterns due to having standardised on a model of one `.feature` per API route. However this is only possible if we can parameterise the `retry until` terms. Otherwise this would mean writing multiple features to support different retry combinations.

---Example of reusing `retry until` from comments---

To maintain a single `get_notification_ref.feature` rather than one for each `until` combination, provide external `until` parameters in the call that can be used by the `retry` within the .feature.

**Implementation that relies on specifying the until parameters inside the .feature file. End up with GET Notification feature file for each retry combination :**

```
Scenario: Get notification & wait for status
   * call read('classpath:NotifyV1/get_notification_ref_wait_status.feature')
   .
   .

Scenario: Get notification & wait for status indicator colour
   * def expectedColour = 'GREEN'
   * call read('classpath:NotifyV1/get_notification_ref_wait_colour.feature')
```

get_notification_ref_wait_status.feature

```
Scenario: Get notification and wait on response status = 200
    Given path 'notification', notificationTypeReference
    And retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method get
    * def notificationResponse = $
```

get_notification_ref_wait_colour.feature

```
Scenario: Get notification and wait on response status = 200 and colour
    Given path 'notification', notificationTypeReference
    And retry until responseStatus == 200 && response.statusColour == expectedColour
    When method get
    * def notificationResponse = $
```

**Implementation of the above that can handle parameterised retry until's  would look like this - note there is now only one GET Notification feature file:**

```
Scenario: Get notification & wait for status 200
   * call read('classpath:NotifyV1/get_notification_ref.feature')
   .
   .

Scenario: Get notification & wait for status 200 and indicator colour
   * def UntilTerm = function(response){ return karate.match(response, '{statusColour: "GREEN"}').pass }
   * call read('classpath:NotifyV1/get_notification_ref.feature')
```

get_notification_ref.feature

```
Scenario: Get notification
    * def untilTerm = karate.get('UntilTerm') ? UntilTerm : function(response){ return true }
    * def untilStatus = karate.get('UntilStatus') ? UntilStatus : 200
    Given path 'notification', notificationTypeReference
    And retry until responseStatus == untilStatus && untilTerm(response)
    When method get
    * def notificationResponse = $
    * karate.set('UntilTerm',null)
    * karate.set('UntilStatus',null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say `retry until` may be sufficient. Since you can tweak the default time and interval, you can set this differently even at the point of need, i.e. a specific HTTP call: https://github.com/intuit/karate#retry-until

Unless you really truly have a way for the external process to call back - and in that case you can look at `karate.signal()` and friends. Otherwise I think you are better off sticking to `retry until`.

Comment: Thank you. Will look at ways to keep the retry configs maintainable

Comment: Each of our API routes is in a separate .feature. We therefore do not want to have to have a variant of each API route .feature if a calling scenario needs 'retry until responseStatus ==200' only and another scenario needs both 'retry until responseStatus ==200 && response.colour == 'GREEN'. Is there latitude to compile the until terms prior to calling "retry until" e.g. bit like a query builder?

Comment: @mactwixs not sure I understand. you can use a pre-defined function if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

Comment: have updated the original post with an example. My bad to try cramming it into a comment line.

Comment: Can you confirm how retry until treats null (if we were to parameterise the above example)? Thanks

Comment: @mactwixs sorry that is really hard for me to understand. in my above link please can you look for `And retry until isValid(response)` and the JS function defined - and really that is all you need IMO. write a JS function that takes a parameter or two by which you can drive the "variant" behavior. you can declare a JS function that is "global" to all features. Just do it :) Or please open a new question with a *specific* example.