# Is there a way to pass a new request in KarateDSL during retry? Thank you,

Tags: api, testing, karate

My feature is something like this:

```
Scenario:  Searching Value
* def Search = generateRandomNumberFive(111,999)
* call read('classpath:services/common.feature')
Given url domain + '/localhost/mysearch?query=' + Search
And headers scenarioHeaders
And retry until myRecord != $response.suggestions[0].ID == 8
When method get
Then status 200
* def myRecord = $response.suggestions[?(@.ID==8)]
```

I would like iSearch value to be regenerated on succeeding retries. Thanks for your help, everyone and to @peter-thomas in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And retry until myRecord != $response.suggestions[0].ID == 8

That's definitely incorrect. A retry expression has to be pure JS. This is explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

So you should get rid of the `$` - that is JsonPath (not JS).

```
And retry until myRecord != response.suggestions[0].ID == 8
```

If you need the `Search` to be re-generated, I think your only option is to loop manually, see [`polling.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature). The way that the Karate `retry until` works is that it will re-play the request as-is and you can't modify it.

Comment: I would like to re-generate Search value and re-run the request with new Search value. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Drachir I already said that it is not possible unless you write a loop manually. please read my answer carefully. If you feel so strongly about this, kindly contribute code, this is open source.