# How to make an If statement restarting the test in Karate

Tags: javascript, java, automated-tests, cucumber, karate

Have a very specific situation that i need to restart the test when my "if" statement is returning true.

Tried just to recall the same feature but seems not working.

```
Scanario: Test example
Given url TEST_URL
When method post
* if (response.fieldName <= 0) { karate.callSingle('feature_path.feature') }
```

Summarizing, would like that once the if statement is true then the test should restart from beginning

Thanks

Comment: if the linked thread does not answer your question, please assume this is not supported and you are welcome to contribute code. also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50348629/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475