# How to print a log incase retry until condition is true in karate

Tags: logging, karate

Is there a way to print the actual and expected value before the retry happens in karate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom logging with `retry until` can work if you use custom functions, within which you do the logging you want.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69274504/143475

Otherwise you can contribute code or [write your own polling loop](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#polling).