# [karate]: retrieve an id in the response of a query and then reuse it in the next

Tags: karate

I have a problem recovering an id at the end of executing a very simple request 1 of this type:

```
Given path "blah"
And header Authorization = "Bearer " + token
And request req
When method post
Then status 201

* def ts_id = response.id
```

Most of the time I recover the `ts_id` well, but I have the impression that this is not always the case. Thus the request 2 which follows the request 1 and which needs the `ts_id` returns an error 400.

The request 2 fails:

```
Given path 'toto', ts_id, 'tata'
And header Authorization = "Bearer " + token
And request req
When method post
Then status 200
```

Here'es the following error:

status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 118, url...

My test is very simple and has no overlap or external call
I don’t know how to deal with this random problem.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because your first response is changing. There is no way to troubleshoot this unless you provide a way to replicate. Let me say that it is highly unlikely to be an issue with Karate.

That said, see if `retry until` is the solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475