# Checking for the presence of a Request header in Karate

Tags: request, http-headers, karate

I am trying to create a mock server for handling functional tests in Karate. For that purpose I need to match certain incoming requests based on certain elements like method, path and presence of "Authorization" header in the incoming requests.

The condition I have is something like:

```
methodIs('get') && pathMatches('/mypath')
```

I need to write a condition for the presence of an "Authorization" header in the request.

As per documentation, we can use:

```
karate.get('requestHeaders.Authorization[0]') == 'foo'
```

However, when I am trying to use the above, it isn't working. I checked for the presence of `requestHeaders.Authorization[0]` but that is being returned as `Null`. My idea was to modify the above to something like `karate.get('requestHeaders.Authorization[0]') == '#notnull'`.

I ended up trying `headerContains('Authorization','')`, which seems to be working - however I am not sure if that is the right way to check for the presence of that specific header. Is there any other (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We are planning to improve this in a future release: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1962

Meanwhile I would have thought that a simple JavaScript condition like `requestHeaders.Authorization` would work. For e.g:

```
Scenario: requestHeaders.Authorization && methodIs('get')
```

Unfortunately it is case-sensitive, which is what we plan to fix in a future release. You could use an OR condition for the time being.

For more explanation, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your reply. Unfortunately the `requestHeaders.authorization` isn't working. In my headers, I notice the lower case header though I have tried both. However I did a pretty print of the `requestHeaders` and I do see the `authorization` header there, which is an array. However, I tried `requestHeaders.Authorization != undefined` and that seems to be working ok.

Comment: (I meant `requestHeaders.authorization != undefined`)

Comment: @AdityaK okay, thanks for the details. I'll try to improve this for the future. p.s: how are things otherwise Mr. Songwala ;)

Comment: Oh my God. It took me a while to get it but I get it now. I will message you separately, if that's ok!

Comment: @AdityaK sure, that's ok :)