# If-None-Match header in karate mock

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I want to create a mock with karate to act on `If-None-Match` header.  I tried to do what is shown [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#requestheaders)

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/path') && methodIs('get') && karate.get('requestHeaders.If-None-Match[0]') == '1'
   * def responseStatus = 304
   * def responseHeaders = { 'ETag': '1' }
```

It is not working. It is ignoring the `karate.get` part, and using the scenario defined after (the same one without headers):

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/path') && methodIs('get')
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: we may need to improve header support. see this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245287/143475 - and if you provide a way to replicate, we can investigate and improve this for future releases: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this. I was able to get a response match.

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/path') && methodIs('get') && headerContains('If-None-Match', '1')
* def responseStatus = 200
* def responseHeaders = {'Etag':'1' }
```