# Retry until response.results[-1].trans.id.includes('TransactionID')

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, karate, jsonpath

Apologies if this has been answered before, I spent most of today looking and found some similar issues but nothing that answered my specific problem.

I am posting to a TransactionAPI with 'TransactionID'-> sleeping thread for 10 minutes (because this is ensures that the transaction posts in the next step) -> calling read api with

```
Then match response.results[*].trans.id contains TransactionID
```

this currently works, but sleep isn't great.. and I wanted to take full advantage of karate.
The [*] is because the new TransactionID appears in the final index of the returned array response.
so the first time it calls the readAPI it gets an array of [5], and the new TransactionID will appear in [6] (and I couldn't figure out how to make it get array.length + 1 and wait for that one to appear)

Reading the responses here [Karate framework retry until not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820690/karate-framework-retry-until-not-working-as-expected/55823180#55823180) and the linked ones inside i tried a few things:

```
And retry until response.results[-1].trans.id.includes('TransactionID')
```

```
And retry until response.results[(@.length-1)].trans.id.includes('TransactionID')
```

These return an error:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:18 Expected an operand but found error
```

I tried the in-line javascript function mentioned in the above link, but could not get it to work either.

Javascript function mentioned:

```
* def isValid = function(x){ return karate.match(x, { tokens: '##[_ > 0]' }).pass }
# ...
And retry until isValid(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

So indexing to `-1` will not work because that is JsonPath and not JavaScript.

Try this:

```
# set this by doing a call before if needed
* def prevLength = response.length
* def isValid = function(x){ return x.length > prevLength }
# ...
* retry until isValid(response)
```

My guess is that it is more than enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @peter-thomas! That doesn't seem to work.. I am positive I am doing something incorrectly but can't seem to figure it out.

```Given url readTransactionsEndPoint
    And headers
    And request
    """
    """
    * def prevLength = response.length
    * print 'prevLength is ' + prevLength
    * def isValid = function(x){ return x.length > prevLength }
# ...
    And retry until isValid(response)
    When method post
    Then status 200```

returns "JS Failed, response is not defined"

karate.get('response.length') is also not working

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I give up. follow this process if you can: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue