# Karate marks the test as failed even though retry until condition is satisfied after retry attempts

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where the field on which I am putting the condition is absent in the response. Eventually, after some retry attempts, that field appears in the response and the condition is satisfied.
Still, the test case is marked as failed with the initial reason that the field is undefined.

[image]

Comment: never had this reported before. I think the only way to make any progress on this is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I will submit the issue with the details

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to proceed if you write better JS logic. By the way, if `zip_local` is a string, you can avoid the `toString()`. So try this:

```
* def isValid = 
"""
function() {
    let zipLocal = karate.get('response.address.zip_local');
    return zipLocal ? zipLocal.includes('4521') : false;
}
"""
# ...
* retry until isValid()
```

Also refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475

Take the help of someone good at JavaScript if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I just tweaked your function a little and it worked.

I needed to check the variable is not undefined before my validation.


    * def isValid =
      """
      function(x,y) {
       if(typeof x !== "undefined")
          return x.contains(y)
      }
      """

Comment: @DeepakRai great, `karate.get()` should normally take care of undefined etc. but ok. please accept the answer