# Karate combine retry until and compareImage

Tags: karate

I want to test if a fetched thumbnail is correct. It might not correct the first time, so I want to retry every couple of seconds. That's why I want to combine retry until and compareImage. Is there any way to achieve this?

This is what I currently have:

```
@getThumnailAndCompare
Scenario: Get thumbnail and compare to reference file
  * configure imageComparison = { engine: 'ssim', failureThreshold: 0.5 }
  * configure retry = { count: 3, interval: 2000 }

  Given url 'https://127.0.0.1:8443'
  And header Accept = 'image/jpeg'
  And path 'api/thumbnail'

  * def expectedThumbnail = 'classpath:thumbnails/expected.jpg'
  And retry until responseStatus == 200 && karate.match("karate.compareImage(expectedThumbnail, response) == '#present'").pass

  When method GET
```

It works fine when the thumbnail matches on first try. I added the karate.match for the check to succeed. Is there a better way?

But when it first fails and then even passes on the 2nd or 3rd try, the scenario still fails due to ImageCompare throwing (see below). This is where I'm stuck.

```
08:26:05.519 [main] INFO  c.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime - classpath:com/barco/nexxis/nmsplus/common/thumbnail.feature - call by tag at line 22: getThumbnailAndCompare
08:26:10.941 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - image comparison failed: latest image differed from baseline more than allowable threshold: 55.89009307671784% >= 0.5%
08:26:11.010 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - retry condition evaluation failed: js failed:
>>>>
01: responseStatus == 200 && karate.match("karate.compareImage(expectedThumbnail, response) == '#present'").pass
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
>>>>
01: karate.compareImage(expectedThumbnail, response)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: latest image differed from baseline more than allowable threshold: 55.89009307671784% >= 0.5%
- com.intuit.karate.ImageComparison.checkMismatch(ImageComparison.java:211)
- com.intuit.karate.ImageComparison.compare(ImageComparison.java:196)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.compareImageInternal(ScenarioEngine.java:1068)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.compareImage(ScenarioBridge.java:293)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

- com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.fromJsEvalException(JsEngine.java:224)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1192)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2143)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2062)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.match(ScenarioEngine.java:1729)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.match(ScenarioBridge.java:643)
- java.base/java.lang.invoke.SpreadHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(SpreadHandle.java:100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow that's a pretty impressive use of Karate. What I suggest is to use `karate.get('response')` which will ensure the "current" value is retrieved. I don't think you are using `karate.match()` or `karate.compareImage()` correctly, so try this:

```
* def imageOk =
"""
function(expectedThumbnail) {
  var status = karate.get('responseStatus');
  if (status != 200) {
    karate.log('response is not 200, will retry');
    return false;
  }
  var bytes = karate.get('responseBytes');      
  var result = karate.compareImage(expectedThumbnail, bytes);
  karate.log('image compare result:', result);
  if (result.mismatchPercentage > 5) {
    karate.log('mismatch percentage is too high, will retry');
    return false;    
  }
  return true;
}
"""
# ...
* retry until imageOk('classpath:thumbnails/expected.jpg')
```

The above code is guesswork and I have not tested it. Would be great if you confirm what `karate.compareImage()` returns as a JSON and whether using `mismatchPercentage` works as expected. Also I assumed `responseBytes` is a better option, but use `response` if that is what works for you.

I don't think that `karate.match()` was going to do what you were expecting. Guess you have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475).

Comment: `karate.compareImage()` returns a JSON if it passes. It throws when it fails, so I had to use try/catch (see actual code in separate Answer). Also, `responseBytes` works just as well as `response`. It works as expected now, thank you.

Comment: @StanAllosserie thanks ! I've opened an issue to see if we really need the exception to be thrown: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2352

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to input from @Peter Thomas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76586756/5714195)

```
@getThumnailAndCompare
Scenario: Get thumbnail and compare to reference file
* configure imageComparison = { engine: 'ssim', failureThreshold: 0.5 }
* configure retry = { count: 3, interval: 2000 }

* def imageOk =
"""
function(expectedThumbnail) {
  let result;
  let bytes = karate.get('responseBytes');
  try {
    result = karate.compareImage(expectedThumbnail, bytes);
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
  karate.log('image comparison passed: mismatch percentage', result.mismatchPercentage);
  return true;
}

Given url 'https://127.0.0.1:8443'
And header Accept = 'image/jpeg'
And path 'api/thumbnail'

* def expectedThumbnail = 'classpath:thumbnails/expected.jpg'
And retry until responseStatus == 200 && imageOk(expectedThumbnail)

When method GET
```

Which looks like this in the Karate log (failed on first try, passed on 2nd):

```
16:09:33.985 [main] INFO  c.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime - classpath:com/barco/nexxis/nmsplus/common/thumbnail.feature - call by tag at line 41: getThumbnailAndCompare
16:09:39.578 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - image comparison failed: latest image differed from baseline more than allowable threshold: 70.38046778537107% >= 0.5%
16:09:44.449 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - image comparison passed: mismatch percentage 0.007713686635135719
```