Karate framework how to fetch the retry count when using retry until in my test
I am facing a scenario where I want to check three different assertions in a single GET call. But all these must be done in a stipulated time.
Example:
Assume, the GET call is made and the same GET call must be retried 20 times with a sleep interval of 6000 ms.
Scenario:

Check the response code is 200 or not. If not break and stop execution. Otherwise continue the next check.
Check if one of an object value is not eql to "test1" or "test2". If value is eql to one of these, break and stop execution. Otherwise continue to check the next assertion.
Retry until getting the same object value as "expected_status". If object value is not getting after maximum number of retries, fail the test. If not pass the test.

My approach to the problem is to change the retry count differently by splitting the assertion (2) and (3) as different scenarios and change the retry count dynamically. Is there any way to fetch the retry count done by the previous scenario?

No, there is no way to fetch the retry count from the previous scenario. You could try to update a scenario variable in your retry function.
For such a detailed requirement, I think the best thing to do is write your own code to do the polling.
A JavaScript example can be found here.
Keep in mind that Karate's Java interop means that if you are willing to write a bit of one-time logic in Java, you can do anything you want. Refer this AWS DynamoDB example.

Thanks @Peter Thomas. Do you mean retry count can be fetched from the same scenario? is there any way to capture it in the current scenario? IMO this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79246940/retry-until-on-reusable-helper-feature-files/79259461#79259461" won't solve my problem.
